# strapi index error when i try to save anything

Tags: strapi

Every time I save anything in my Strapi application
I am getting this error:

```
error: alter table "account_landings_components" add constraint "account_landings_unique" unique ("entity_id", "component_id", "field", "component_type") - relation "account_landings_unique" already exists
    at Parser.parseErrorMessage node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:287:98)
```

Different tables show these index error.

I am using the following in `package.json`:

```json
"@strapi/strapi": "4.7.0", 
"@strapi/plugin-users-permissions": "4.7.0",
"@strapi/plugin-i18n": "4.7.0",
```

Comment: Have you restored your database or is it fresh? Are you sure your index is correct, what DB are you using?

Comment: i am using postgresql.  "pg": "^8.6.0", "pg-connection-string": "^2.5.0". Database is not fresh it already has allot of data.

Comment: When these types of errors occur for me using postgres, it is due to an indexing error and it honestly has only happened due to me restoring a database from a backup and perhaps data being saved in the interim. I'd try reindexing your table or DB and see if that works (i.e. `REINDEX TABLE account_landings_components`)...here are some doc references: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-reindex.html my question then becomes, if this is actually an indexing error, how it happened because normal usage should never create that issue

Comment: I would suggest to make a pg_dump, restore on local environment, migrate local version of strapi to 4.8.0, run another local instance with fresh database, transfer data between them. (i think transfer introduced 4.8.0)

Comment: Other then that seems you have some database issues, unless you know how to work with postgres in depth, you likely not going to sort it...

Answer (score 0):

In config/database.js file
there is `setting` attribute
it was false. I change it to true and now it is not showing that problem.
Thanks for your kind comment every one.

```
settings: {
    forceMigration: true,
  },
```